# Passing matrix as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am new to c, I am using CUDA compiler. I want to declare five matrices, from a[1][1] to a[5][5]. Initialize them with random values. Print these values. I have shown the whole code I wrote. I face problems

1. Passing matrix as parameter
2. Initialize a matrix (should be constant)

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void printMatrix(int **a, int rows, int cols)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
           for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
               printf("%d\t", a[i][j] );
           }
           printf("\n");
       }
   }

   int main() {
       int N;

       for (int n=0; n<=5; n++)
           N = n;
           int a[N][N];

           for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
               for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
                   a[i][j] = rand() % 256;
               }

           printf("Matrix A\n");
           printMatrix(a, 10, 10);
       }
   }
   ```

   This works fine if i define N on the top. If I did that, I couldn't change N value using for loop. How can I correct.

Comment: "Initialize a matrix (should be constant)" It is not clear what you mean. What should be constant? The array data? The array size? Why do you need the `N` variable to begin with? Also, please post the actual code that compiles.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is a typo in the program. You omitted the open brace after the loop statement

```
for (int n=0; n<=5; n++)
                        ^^^^
    N = n;
    int a[N][N];
    //...
```

There should be

```
for (int n=0; n<=5; n++) {
                        ^^^^
    N = n;
    int a[N][N];
    //...
```

Array `a` is a variable length array. Its dimension may not be equal to 0. So the variable `n` must to start from 1 as it is written in the assignment

```
for (int n=1; n<=5; n++) {
         ^^^^
```

This function call

```
printMatrix(a, 10, 10);
               ^^  ^^
```

does not make sense because the number 10 has nothing common with the array.

And the function declaration

```
void printMatrix(int **a, int rows, int cols);
                 ^^^^^^^
```

is invalid. There is a mismatch between the argument type and the parameter type and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another type.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void printMatrix( size_t rows, size_t cols, int a[][cols] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) printf( "%3d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    const int UPPER_VALUE = 256;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t n = 1; n <= N; n++ )
    {
        int a[n][n];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) a[i][j] = rand() % UPPER_VALUE;
        }

        printf( "Matrix A[%zu][%zu]:\n", n, n );
        printMatrix( n, n, a );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
Matrix A[1][1]:
117 

Matrix A[2][2]:
 57 216 
 50 233 

Matrix A[3][3]:
 42 117 215 
177 218  26 
202  81 163 

Matrix A[4][4]:
205 178 157   2 
229 165  93  94 
 91 160  39 205 
 26 242 131  69 

Matrix A[5][5]:
147 248 126 107  42 
103 149 160  62  70 
122  89  17 203 252 
222 125 154 224  98 
 63  61 192 155 222
```

If the compiler does not support variable length arrays then you have to allocate the arrays dynamically. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void printMatrix( int **a, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) printf( "%3d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    const int UPPER_VALUE = 256;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t n = 1; n <= N; n++ )
    {
        int **a = malloc( n * sizeof( int * ) );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            a[i] = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) a[i][j] = rand() % UPPER_VALUE;
        }

        printf( "Matrix A[%zu][%zu]:\n", n, n );
        printMatrix( a, n, n );
        printf( "\n" );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( a[i] );
        free( a );
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you would do `int a[][cols]` instead of `int a[rows][cols]`? The array parameter decays into an array pointer in either case, but the latter form might give slightly better type safety.

Comment: @Lundin I made by analogy void f( int a[], size_t n ); :) Of course it can be written as you showed.:)

Comment: @Lundin For example if the function at first would be only declared I write its declaration the following way void printMatrix( size_t, size_t, int [][*] );

Comment: I guess it is a matter of style. I always name the parameters in the prototype and make sure they are identical to the function definition.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - Thank you, since I am using CUDA C compiler, this is not compiling. I get "a parameter is not allowed" at line 5 and "expression must be a constant value" at line 23

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran If the compiler does not support C99 then you should allocate the array dynamically in the loop.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow still I face compilation error, (a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int **") at line 23 and (a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *") at line 27

Comment: @VladfromMoscow and why are you allocating `n`, since it's a matrix shouldn't we allocate n*n ?

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran In this case you will not be able to apply twice the subscript operator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I still face problem to compile the second code

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n=0; n<=5; n++){  /* <--missing { which causes N to be 6 after last iteration */
 //your code
}
```

You missed a `{` after first `for` loop in `main` that's why `int a[N][N]` and other loops are not inside its body (*which you probably want "changing value of* N *"*)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the number of matrices is constant, so just #define it at the top. Without touching your printMatrix method, you can have a main body as follows:

```
#define N 5
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int **data[N]; // Array of length N of int **, where each int ** will store a matrix.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int matrixSize = i + 1; // creating the ith matrix
        data[i] = malloc(matrixSize * sizeof *data[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            data[i][j] = malloc(matrixSize * sizeof *data[i][j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixSize; k++) {
                data[i][j][k] = rand() % 256;
            }
        }
    }
    // Printing the first one
    printMatrix(data[0], 1, 1);

    // don't forget to loop again to free the buffers allocated...
    return 0;
}
```